# parameter name being omitted in c programming

Tags: c

hello im currently having trouble running this program. it keeps popping an error message with parameter name omitted. Any suggestions?

```
int addarray (int *,int);

int main(void){

int array1 [10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
    array2 [4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
int i;
int total = 0;
int total2 = 0;

for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    total += array1[i];
}
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    total2 += array2[i];
}

printf("The sum of the elements in array1 is %d. \n", addarray(array1, 10));

printf("The sum of the elements in array2 is %d. \n", addarray(array2, 4));

return 0;
}

int addarray (int *,int){
int array1 [10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
    array2 [4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
int i;
int total = 0;
int total2 = 0;

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        total += array1[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        total2 += array2[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the error message ?

Comment: It seems like you aren't returning anything in your function, for starters, and you aren't using any parameters so you will have another error.

Comment: It looks like you must be having trouble *compiling* your program.  You need to learn the difference.  Compiling is a prerequisite for running, to be sure, but compile-time issues are a completely separate beast from run-time issues.

Comment: yes it says parameter name omitted for : int addarray (int *, int)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but more urgently, you need to read about creating an MCVE ([MCVE]).  What you've got is close to an MCVE, but doesn't include the headers.  When you have a compilation problem, you should show the exact message from compiling the exact source code you show (line numbers should be spot on).  Remove irrelevant code and most comments.  Do indent your code in an orthodox style (1TBS or Allman recommended). Don't use tabs; use spaces.  Don't leave spaces before the subscripts on arrays in declarations — a style issue.

Comment: So now you've fixed the code in question thus rendering the question invalid.

Answer (score 2):

You have to give name to the argument in addarray function, for ex:

```
int addarray (int *a, int b) {
```

Comment: You might observe that it is legal, though not necessarily a good idea, to omit the parameter names from the declaration at the top of the file, but it is not permissible in C to omit the parameter names in the function, even if you are not going to use the parameters.  C++ does allow you to omit the parameter names in the function if you're not going to use the parameter.  That happens when your function must match a particular signature but this implementation of the signature doesn't need to use some or all of the arguments that are part of the signature.